# monacaでIOSアプリのビルドエラーについて

Tags: ios, monaca, cordova

monacaにてinappbrowserとncmb-pushを使ったプッシュ通知付きのウェブビューアプリを作成したのですが、monacaデバッガーでは正常に起動してエラーログなし。
デバッグビルドをするとエラーでビルドできません。
androidは正常にビルドでき、IOSのみビルドできません。

以下エラーログになります。

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC Build/Intermediates/MonacaApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MonacaApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate+MonacaPushNotification.o MonacaApp/Plugins/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/AppDelegate+MonacaPus Notification.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error executing command: xcodebuild


Build error: Error building project source code
```

どなたかご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーログを見ると、MonacaBackendプラグインが組み込まれているようですが、
MonacaBackendプラグインとNifty用プラグインは競合してしまうため、両方入れた
場合はビルドに失敗します。
MonacaBackendプラグインを外してみてはいかがでしょうか？

また、質問されるときは、使っているCordovaバージョン、組み込んだ全プラグインと
そのバージョンについて記載した方が良いと思います。